# Change auto-renaming in guake

Tags: linux, terminal

Is there any way to remove path from tab name in guake? I want to have auto-renaming, but without a path. Usually I open several hosts in different tabs and rename them all according to the host name. It is annoying to make the same action on every new tab. Default behavior (vte.get_window_title()) is not convenient because tab name has path in it. I don't need any path in tab, and also usually names with path are very long.

Comment: // , Good question! I have it too. Could you format it a little better, please, though, Oleksii? This is hard to read, and "change auto-renaming in guake" could refer to anything from renaming files to tab completion. 
Thanks for adding your knowledge to our pool, though. This problem has frustrated me, as well.

Comment: // , Not sure why people are so quick to downvote on this site, especially for new users who are obviously not trolls or spammers, simply unfamiliar.

Comment: // , I mean, at least say *why* you have chosen to condemn a particular post, which usually represents a great deal of frustration on the part of the poster, to the trash heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.
first step
gconftool-2 --set /apps/guake/general/use_vte_titles true
I want to have the autorenaming. but I need to change its behavior.
Second step is changing autorenaming in the shell
I use ZSH as a command shell
So, I added following code to .zshrc

```
case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        precmd () {print -Pn "\e]0;%n@%m\a"}
        ;;
esac
```

So I have autorenameing without path.

But it is helpless when I use ssh. In this case I still have path in name, unless I do the same on remote server.

Comment: // , Cool to see another ZSH user. Any idea why "it is helpless when I use ssh."? That is an interesting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Install gconf-editor.

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Start gconf-editor

```
gconf-editor
```

Browse to apps/general/guake/general.

On the right hand side, uncheck the “use_vte_titles” item and close it and restart guake.

All tabs would be named “Terminal” and renaming would preserve it.

The technical reason for doing this is the following piece of code:

```
def on_terminal_title_changed(self, vte, box):
    use_them = self.client.get_bool(KEY("/general/use_vte_titles"))
    if not use_them:
        return
    page = self.notebook.page_num(box)
    self.tabs.get_children()[page].set_label(vte.get_window_title())
```

As we can see ‘use_vte_titles' key prevents the autorenaming feature

Comment: it's not an answer on my question. I want to have autorenaming, but different than vte.get_window_title(). It seems you read just first sentence of my question. I updated question. it should be more clear now.

Comment: // , This was not clear to me from the question, Oleksii. I think you're right, though, this answer only seems to *prevent* the default automatic renaming. It does not seem to allow the kind of automatic renaming that you're looking for. @Babbzzz, thanks for answering, would you be willing to edit the question for formatting and, perhaps, update the answer to allow for automatic renaming, still?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue bugging me. I don't know what you mean by auto-renaming but maybe this command will help you

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/guake/general/use_vte_titles --type boolean false
```

After this command all the windows are simply named "Terminal". This solves the issue of the long names.

Alternatively, I found a post in a forum [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=143201) that makes the tab names appear as "Terminal $n", where $n is an increasing natural number. Maybe this is what you're looking for.

Hope this helps.